# Android SQLite Exception: no such column

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I added a date field to my database, but I got an error which sais "No such column named date".
Can anyone point out where is my mistake?

```
    private static final String UID = "id";
        private static final String NAME = "Bmi";
        private static final String _STATUS = "status";
        private static final String WEIGHT = "weight";
        private static final String DATE = "curDate";    

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + UID + " integer primary key autoincrement," +
                            "" + NAME + " VARCHAR(50), " +
                            "" + _STATUS + " VARCHAR(255)," +
                            "" + WEIGHT + " VARCHAR(255)," +
                            "" + DATE + "TEXT);");
```

Comment: it is a typo ... log your create statement and find out where did you forget about space

Comment: Perhaps you should use "curDate" instead of "date"

Comment: `  "" + DATE + "TEXT);");` here there is no space between your DATE variable  and `TEXT` , this cause the result like `curDateTEXT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a space here

```
"" + DATE + "TEXT);");
```

It has to be

```
"" + DATE + " TEXT);");
```

---

Note: uninstall and reinstall your app, to get the database re-created on next launch.

Comment: Then you have another problem. You're using an object which hasn't been yet instanced.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is a **bad habit to use name of SQL inbuilt function** as a table name correct your 'DATE' name to something else and there is a typo on the same line of DATE rename table and put the space before text like this. 
+ CUR_DATE + " TEXT") (CUR_DATE is suggested name).